# Running ReportGenerator using cake build on teamcity (Exec format error)

Tags: .net-core, teamcity, xunit, cakebuild, reportgenerator

I'm trying to generate test coverage report and view on teamcity after my project build is complete. So far I have been able to make it work on my local machine (windows) without any issue. The report is generating and I am able to view the coverage reports (html files generated) but it is failing on teamcity (project building with linux agent) with the error below:

```
Error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Exec format error)
  ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (8): Exec format error
    at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
    at Cake.Core.IO.ProcessRunner.Start(FilePath filePath, ProcessSettings settings) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\IO\ProcessRunner.cs:line 67
    at Cake.Core.Tooling.Tool`1.RunProcess(TSettings settings, ProcessArgumentBuilder arguments, ProcessSettings processSettings) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\Tooling\Tool.cs:line 215
    at Cake.Core.Tooling.Tool`1.Run(TSettings settings, ProcessArgumentBuilder arguments, ProcessSettings processSettings, Action`1 postAction) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\Tooling\Tool.cs:line 101
    at Cake.Core.Tooling.Tool`1.Run(TSettings settings, ProcessArgumentBuilder arguments) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\Tooling\Tool.cs:line 81
    at Cake.Common.Tools.ReportGenerator.ReportGeneratorRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 reports, DirectoryPath targetDir, ReportGeneratorSettings settings) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Common\Tools\ReportGenerator\ReportGeneratorRunner.cs:line 66
    at Cake.Common.Tools.ReportGenerator.ReportGeneratorAliases.ReportGenerator(ICakeContext context, IEnumerable`1 reports, DirectoryPath targetDir, ReportGeneratorSettings settings) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Common\Tools\ReportGenerator\ReportGeneratorAliases.cs:line 151
    at Cake.Common.Tools.ReportGenerator.ReportGeneratorAliases.ReportGenerator(ICakeContext context, String pattern, DirectoryPath targetDir, ReportGeneratorSettings settings) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Common\Tools\ReportGenerator\ReportGeneratorAliases.cs:line 71
    at Submission#0.ReportGenerator(String pattern, DirectoryPath targetDir, ReportGeneratorSettings settings) in :line 356
    at Submission#0.<<Initialize>>b__0_4() in /opt/buildagent/work/[some folder]/build.cake:line 150
    at Cake.Core.CakeTaskBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<Does>b__0(ICakeContext context) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\CakeTaskBuilder.Execution.cs:line 26
    at Cake.Core.CakeTaskBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<Does>b__0(ICakeContext x) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\CakeTaskBuilder.Execution.cs:line 83
    at Cake.Core.CakeTask.Execute(ICakeContext context) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\CakeTask.cs:line 125
    at Cake.Core.DefaultExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync(CakeTask task, ICakeContext context) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\DefaultExecutionStrategy.cs:line 87
    at Cake.Core.CakeEngine.ExecuteTaskAsync(ICakeContext context, IExecutionStrategy strategy, Stopwatch stopWatch, CakeTask task, CakeReport report) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\CakeEngine.cs:line 336
    at Cake.Core.CakeEngine.ExecuteTaskAsync(ICakeContext context, IExecutionStrategy strategy, Stopwatch stopWatch, CakeTask task, CakeReport report) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\CakeEngine.cs:line 361
    at Cake.Core.CakeEngine.ExecuteTaskAsync(ICakeContext context, IExecutionStrategy strategy, Stopwatch stopWatch, CakeTask task, CakeReport report) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\CakeEngine.cs:line 369
    at Cake.Core.CakeEngine.RunTask(ICakeContext context, IExecutionStrategy strategy, CakeTask task, String target, Stopwatch stopWatch, CakeReport report) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\CakeEngine.cs:line 284
    at Cake.Core.CakeEngine.RunTargetAsync(ICakeContext context, IExecutionStrategy strategy, ExecutionSettings settings) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\CakeEngine.cs:line 247
    at Cake.Scripting.BuildScriptHost.RunTargetAsync(String target) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake\Scripting\BuildScriptHost.cs:line 47
    at Cake.Core.Scripting.ScriptHost.RunTarget(String target) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\Scripting\ScriptHost.cs:line 191
    at Submission#0.<<Initialize>>d__0.MoveNext() in /opt/buildagent/work/[some folder]/build.cake:line 346
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.ScriptExecutionState.RunSubmissionsAsync[TResult](ImmutableArray`1 precedingExecutors, Func`2 currentExecutor, StrongBox`1 exceptionHolderOpt, Func`2 catchExceptionOpt, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script`1.RunSubmissionsAsync(ScriptExecutionState executionState, ImmutableArray`1 precedingExecutors, Func`2 currentExecutor, Func`2 catchExceptionOpt, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Cake.Scripting.Roslyn.RoslynScriptSession.Execute(Script script) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake\Scripting\Roslyn\RoslynScriptSession.cs:line 136
    at Cake.Core.Scripting.ScriptRunner.Run(IScriptHost host, FilePath scriptPath, IDictionary`2 arguments) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\Scripting\ScriptRunner.cs:line 219
    at Cake.Commands.BuildCommand.Execute(CakeOptions options) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake\Commands\BuildCommand.cs:line 41
    at Cake.CakeApplication.Run(CakeOptions options) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake\CakeApplication.cs:line 45
    at Cake.Program.Main() in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake\Program.cs:line 80
 Process exited with code 1
```

I tried with dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool as well, encountered same error.
I also specified the ToolPath for ReportGenerator to run using the .dll instead of .exe for both ReportGenerator and dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool, still no luck.

Please find part of my cake script below:

```
#tool nuget:?package=ReportGenerator
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Coverlet

// define variables
...

Task("Test")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        var resultsFolder = Directory(@".\coverage\");

        if (testProjectFiles != null)
        {
            var settings = new DotNetCoreTestSettings
            {
                Configuration = "Release"
            };

            foreach (var projectFile in testProjectFiles)
            {
                var coverletSettings = new CoverletSettings {
                    CollectCoverage = true,
                    CoverletOutputFormat = CoverletOutputFormat.opencover,
                    CoverletOutputDirectory = resultsFolder,
                    CoverletOutputName = $"{projectFile.GetFilenameWithoutExtension()}.opencover.xml",
                };

                Information("Running tests in {0}", projectFile.GetFilenameWithoutExtension());
                DotNetCoreTest(projectFile.ToString(), settings, coverletSettings);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Warning("No unit tests found in the solution!");
        }
        
    });

Task("GenerateCoverageReport")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        // Generate test coverage report
        var reportGeneratorSetting = new ReportGeneratorSettings{
            Verbosity = ReportGeneratorVerbosity.Verbose
        };
        
        //  ---> failing on teamcity
        ReportGenerator("./coverage/*.xml", "./coverage", reportGeneratorSetting);
    });
```

Is there anything I'm missing for the ReportGenerator to run on teamcity? Please advise.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cake. But does the global tool work on your Linux build agent without Cake (if you directly execute it from command terminal)? Which Linux distribution do you use? Is is a 64 bit distribution?

Comment: I don't have access to the server on which teamcity is installed.
Yes it is a 64 bit distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the dotnet tool package instead:

```
#module nuget:?package=Cake.DotNetTool.Module&version=0.4.0
#tool dotnet:?package=dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool&version=4.6.7
```

Then invoke Cake twice, first to bootstrap the module:

```
dotnet cake --bootstrap --verbosity=verbose && dotnet cake --verbosity=verbose
```